# Unable to write into directory with vim on 16.04

Tags: vim, nginx

[image]

I'm trying to follow https://www.linode.com/docs/websites/nginx/deploy-django-applications-using-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04 , but I'm getting the error in vim preventing me from inseting the text. I've tried:

```
sudo chmod 757 -R /var/www
```

but no luck. How can I save the file with vim?

Comment: You shouldn't use `chmod -R` (or `chown -R`) unless you know what you're doing. It usually causes lots of issues.

Comment: What does `/var/www` have to do with `/etc/uwsgi`? Do you usually go about changing permissions of random folders? O.o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you are trying to write to `/etc/uwsgi/sites/sample.ini` usually items in `/etc/` are only writeable by the `root` user. So you should run your editor with sudo like this

```
sudo vim /etc/uwsgi/sites/sample.ini
```